# How to call a subroutine from `for` processed items (after `in`)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
set /a "pre+=1
)

for /f %%a in ('call :star') do (
set /a "count=count+10000"
set /a "fi=10000/pre"
set /a "en=!fi!*!count!"
set "br=!en:~0,-6!"
title !br!
)
pause




:star
echo Some stuff.
echo Some more.
exit /b
```

I'm trying to create a progress bar that updates while commands run.
Things have been working well, except I need to be able to use the call command within the for command, and my current setup (below) is not working.

How can I use the call command in a for loop?

Comment: Can you put the :star bit in another batch file and just run that in the `for` loop instead?

Comment: This page tells how to create a function and how to call it. (http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-7-functions.html)

Comment: Between `pause` and `:star`, there sould be an `exit /B` statement in order to not execute `:star` unintentionally after the code above has completed execution;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible directly to call a subroutine from for processed items.

But it's possible to workaround this with this [Aacini's trick](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6302#p6302):

```
@echo off
if /I "%1" equ "call" shift & shift & goto %2

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (
set /a "pre+=1
)

for /f %%a in ('%0 call :star') do (
set /a "count=count+10000"
set /a "fi=10000/pre"
set /a "en=!fi!*!count!"
set "br=!en:~0,-6!"
title !br!
)
pause


exit /b %errorlevel%

:star
echo Some stuff.
echo Some more.
exit /b
```

you need the line `if /I "%1" equ "call" shift & shift & goto %2` at the beginning of your script and then you can call the subroutine with `%0 call :start` form the for loop.

Comment: Between `pause` and `:star`, there sould be an `exit /B` statement in order to not execute `:star` unintentionally after the code above has completed execution;

Comment: After changing line 5 to for /f %%a in ('%0 call :star'), everything worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Read *entire* [`FOR` Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx) or `for /F`:

> If Command Extensions are enabled...
>
> ...
>
> Finally, you can use the `FOR /F` command to parse the output of a
>   command.  You do this by making the file-set between the parenthesis a
>   back quoted string.  It will be treated as a **command line**, which
>   is **passed to a child `CMD.EXE`** and the output is captured into
>   memory and parsed as if it was a file...

Let me specify (elaborate) above statement: `for /F` command captures and parses `STDOUT` output of a command specified.
However, this is empty for `call :star` (as the `Invalid attempt ...` message belongs to the [`STDERR` stream](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)), see next example:

```
==> call :star
Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script.

==> call :star 2>NUL

==>
```